# Apache NiFi put value to serial column

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a database table with following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE fact.cabinet_account (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    account_name text NULL,
    cabinet_id int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cabinet_account_account_name_key UNIQUE (account_name),
    CONSTRAINT cabinet_account_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT cabinet_account_cabinet_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (cabinet_id) REFERENCES fact.cabinet(id)
);
```

And I have a JSON from `InvokeHttp` which I want to put to database:

```
{
  "login" : "some_maild@gmail.com",
  "priority_level" : 5,
  "is_archive" : false
}
```

I'm using `QueryRecord` with this script:

```
SELECT
19 AS cabinet_id, 
login AS account_name
FROM FLOWFILE
```

I'm trying to `UPSERT` in `PutDatabaseRecord` processor and got the error:

```
ERROR: value NULL at column "id"
```

How to put value for serial column with Apache NiFi?

**UPDATE**

My JSON looks like (before `PutDatabase`):

```
[ {
  "account_name" : "email1@maximagroup.ru",
  "priority_level" : 1000,
  "cabinet_id" : 19
}, {
  "account_name" : "email2@gmail.com",
  "priority_level" : 1,
  "cabinet_id" : 19
}, {
  "account_name" : "email3@umww.com",
  "priority_level" : 1000,
  "cabinet_id" : 19
} ]
```

`PutDatabaseRecord` looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try making the operation `INSERT` rather than `UPSERT`

An `UPSERT` needs to check whether the given `id` exists, to know if it should insert or update, which it can't do as no `id` is provided.

Comment: what database is it?

Comment: It's PostgreSQL

Comment: Can you update your question with the flowfile content entering the `PutDatabaseRecord` and the config for `PutDatabaseRecord`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, problem is still here. I updated my question with this information.

Comment: I dont understand how to pass through `id serial NOT NULL` with Apache NiFi.